# Reading text file with numpy.loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy, file-io

I am getting an error when trying to read a text file.

```
import numpy as np

fnam = 'file.txt'
test_fnames = np.loadtxt(fnam, dtype=None, delimiter=',')
test_fnames
```

I now get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

The file content is just a comma separated list of numbers. Perhaps there is a space at the end of the file that is causing an error?

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9122,3,3,45,5,6
```

Thanks. The problem was the way I wrote the text file in Torch7.

Comment: What does the file content looks like?

Comment: If you wish to load in the numbers, then your delimiter should be ','.  Also, try dtype=None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `np.genfromtxt()` instead of `np.loadtxt`.
Because the first one let handles missing values :

```
import numpy as np

fnam = 'file.txt'
test_fnames = np.genfromtxt(fnam, dtype=None, delimiter=',')
```

You could also try :

```
import numpy as np

fnam = 'file.txt'
test_fnames = np.genfromtxt(fnam, dtype=None, delimiter=',')[:,:-1]
```

It's just an idea ^^ But if you want, upload your data file somewhere, give me the link and I will see ;)